# MVC3 Conditional Validation with Entity Framework Model First

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I want to use conditional validation in my application, but i cant't seem to figure it out. The data annotations validation is working fine, and if i leave the field empty with will return to the form with indication of such, but nothing happens for the conditional one. I would very much like if I could keep extra code out of the controller, views, and EF generated files (that's why I'm using the sealed class). ("ConditionIsMet" will obviously be something that returns a boolean and is there just as an example). What am I missing?

This is the code I have so far:

View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
<fieldset>
    <legend>TestApplications</legend>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FullName)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FullName)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FullName)
    </div>

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Create" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>'
```

Controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult TestApplication(TestApplications application)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            DB_connection.TestApplications.Add(application);
            DB_connection.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View();
    }
```

My custom class file:

```
[MetadataType(typeof(TestApplicationsMetadata))]
public partial class TestApplications
{
    internal sealed class TestApplicationsMetadata : IValidatableObject
    {

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Name is required.")]
        public string FullName { get; set; }


        public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
            if (!conditionIsMet)
            {
                yield return new ValidationResult
                 ("Condition was not met", new[] { "FullName" });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not the buddy class, but the class itself should implement `IValidatableObject`:

```
[MetadataType(typeof(TestApplicationsMetadata))]
public partial class TestApplications : IValidatableObject
{
    internal sealed class TestApplicationsMetadata
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Name is required.")]
        public string FullName { get; set; }
    }

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (!conditionIsMet)
        {
            yield return new ValidationResult
             ("Condition was not met", new[] { "FullName" });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @gert-arnold, i changed it, but now it says that 'Models.TestApplications' does not implement interface member 'System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.IValidatableObject.Validate(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ValidationContext)' refering to the original created EF classes.

Comment: Did you move the Validate method?